Template Metaprogramming to eliminate signed-unsigned comparison warnings
Some time ago, I wanted to create the equivalent of the Python ternary comparison operator (a <= b <= c). After getting help in this post, I ended up with a set of functions:
// This helper determines if 'test' is in the range [low, high]
template<typename Low, typename Val, typename High>
bool between(Low const& low, Val const& test, High const& high);

// This helper determines if 'test' is in the range (low, high)
template<typename Low, typename Val, typename High>
bool within(Low const& low, Val const& test, High const& high);

// This helper determines if 'test' is in the range [low, high)
template<typename Low, typename Val, typename High>
bool contained(Low const& low, Val const& test, High const& high);

These work well and have a variety of unit tests to validate their performance. However, recently I discovered that someone turned off the compiler warnings, so I turned them back on and got an unsigned/signed comparison warning on one of the functions. Yes, the warning was valid, but the reality is that signed/unsigned comparisons are often valid and I want to be able to write readable code that isn't obfuscated by casts and such to silence a warning.
This led to an attempt to enhance the code through template metaprogramming to do casting/conversion as needed but not otherwise. I came up with this function to generically compare, and then rewrote my ternary functions based on it:
    template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
    auto cmp(Lhs const& lhs, Rhs const& rhs) -> std::strong_ordering
    {
        using Lhs_t  = std::conditional_t<(std::is_signed<Lhs>() == std::is_signed<Rhs>()),    //
                                         decltype(lhs),
                                         std::make_signed_t<Lhs>>;
        using Rhs_t  = std::conditional_t<(std::is_signed<Lhs>() == std::is_signed<Rhs>()),    //
                                         decltype(rhs),
                                         std::make_signed_t<Rhs>>;
        auto&& lhs_v = static_cast<Lhs_t>(lhs);
        auto&& rhs_v = static_cast<Rhs_t>(rhs);

        return lhs_v <=> rhs_v;
    }

That compiled beautifully and passed my (integer) unit tests. Then I updated all the functions to use this new paradigm and got an error comparing std::string. Clearly, this won't work in that case, so I figured I needed SFINAE and started fighting with std::enable_if. I'm losing the fight.
What I'm trying to do is write one function that will be used if all the arguments are integral (to silence the compiler warning about signed/unsigned comparisons), and another general function to be used for all other types.
Here's where I am now:
    template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
    typename std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_integral_v<Lhs>, std::is_integral_v<Rhs>>, std::strong_ordering>
    cmp(Lhs const& lhs, Rhs const& rhs)
    {
        using Lhs_t  = std::conditional_t<(std::is_signed<Lhs>() == std::is_signed<Rhs>()),    //
                                         decltype(lhs),
                                         std::make_signed_t<Lhs>>;
        using Rhs_t  = std::conditional_t<(std::is_signed<Lhs>() == std::is_signed<Rhs>()),    //
                                         decltype(rhs),
                                         std::make_signed_t<Rhs>>;
        auto&& lhs_v = static_cast<Lhs_t>(lhs);
        auto&& rhs_v = static_cast<Rhs_t>(rhs);

        return lhs_v <=> rhs_v;
    }

    // Non-integral comparisons (e.g., strings)
    template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
    typename std::enable_if_t<std::negation_v<std::conjunction_v<std::is_integral_v<Lhs>, std::is_integral_v<Rhs>>>,
                              std::strong_ordering>
    cmp(Lhs const& lhs, Rhs const& rhs)
    {
        return lhs <=> rhs;
    }

The compiler reports this:
/usr/src/project/util/unit/../bool.hh:20:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/src/project/util/unit/../bool.hh: In substitution of 'template<class Lhs, class Rhs> std::enable_if_t<conjunction_v<is_integral_v<Lhs>, is_integral_v<Rhs> >, std::strong_ordering> {anonymous}::cmp(const Lhs&, const Rhs&) [with Lhs = unsigned int; Rhs = int]':
/usr/src/project/util/unit/../bool.hh:53:28:   required from 'bool is_le(const Lhs&, const Rhs&) [with Lhs = unsigned int; Rhs = int]'
/usr/src/project/util/unit/bool_unittest.cpp:21:5:   required from here
/usr/src/project/util/unit/../bool.hh:19:36: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class ... _Bn> constexpr const bool std::conjunction_v<_Bn ...>'
   19 |     typename std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_integral_v<Lhs>, std::is_integral_v<Rhs>>, std::strong_ordering>
      |                               ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/project/util/unit/../bool.hh:19:36: note:   expected a type, got 'std::is_integral_v<unsigned int>'
/usr/src/project/util/unit/../bool.hh:19:36: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class ... _Bn> constexpr const bool std::conjunction_v<_Bn ...>'
/usr/src/project/util/unit/../bool.hh:19:36: note:   expected a type, got 'std::is_integral_v<int>'

It's clear I'm doing the metaprogramming wrong, but not as clear how to fix it.

For good measure, I'll shout out std::cmp_less and friends: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/intcmp

Thanks @chris. That was really new

I see that you already figured out that std::conjunction_v needs to be std::conjunction instead, but I still want to post this. Personally I find it easier to use the requires clause or concepts (since c++20) instead of std::enable_if. Additionally you can make use of the standard integer comparison functions.
Your code could then be changed to the following (which is more readable IMO):
template <std::integral Lhs, std::integral Rhs>
constexpr auto cmp(const Lhs& lhs, const Rhs& rhs) {
    if (std::cmp_less(lhs, rhs)) {
        return std::strong_ordering::less;
    } else if (std::cmp_greater(lhs, rhs)) {
        return std::strong_ordering::greater;
    } else {
        return std::strong_ordering::equal;
    }
}

constexpr auto cmp(const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
    return lhs <=> rhs;
}

I also marked the functions as constexpr which won't hurt here and made the return type auto so that you can compare e.g. floats, too.

Edit:
I thought, why don't you just use some syntax like the one you showed (a < b < c and similar). Obviously C++ doesn't really work that way, it would convert the first comparisons result to a bool and then compare the last value with this Boolean. But what if you changed the first variables type to something that defines the comparison operators and doesn't return a bool, but some other type that holds the result of the comparison and its second operand? This second type could then again perform comparison and finally return a bool.
#include <compare>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cassert>

template <typename T>
class ComparisonResult;

template <typename T>
class Comparable {
public:
    ComparisonResult<T> operator<(const T& other) const {
        return { that < other, other};
    }
    ComparisonResult<T> operator<=(const T& other) const {
        return { that <= other, other };
    }
    ComparisonResult<T> operator>(const T& other) const {
        return { that > other, other };
    }
    ComparisonResult<T> operator>=(const T& other) const {
        return { that >= other, other };
    }

    const T& that;
};

template <typename T>
class ComparisonResult {
public:
    bool operator<(const T& other) const {
        return success && that < other;
    }
    bool operator<=(const T& other) const {
        return success && that <= other;
    }
    bool operator>(const T& other) const {
        return success && that > other;
    }
    bool operator>=(const T& other) const {
        return success && that >= other;
    }

    bool success;
    const T& that;
};

int main() {
    assert(true == Comparable{ 4 } < 5 < 6);
    assert(true == Comparable{ 4 } <= 4 <= 5);
    assert(false == Comparable{ 4 } < 5 < 4);

    return 0;
}

This would allow things like a < b >= c, too, where you could start arguing if the expression makes sense or should be prohibited. You could change the Comparables comparison operators to return different ComparisonResult types, one for </<= and one for >/>= with only those operators defined again, which would catch something like that at compile time.
You could also add a second template argument to those classes to allow comparing different types (without warnings) and could also apply some additional logic to handle the whole signed/unsigned thing again.

If you want to condense it even further: constexpr auto cmp(std::integral auto lhs, std::integral auto rhs)

will these comparisons do signed/unsigned without warnings? I like this, as I knew what I was doing was too hard.

@jwm Those comparisons do not generate any warnings because they are written in a way that considers signed-/unsignedness. You can look at the standard library implementation (or at least the effect those functions should have) here or just test if they generate warnings like I did here.

@jwm I edited my answer to include some extra classes which could help with comparisons like a < b < c without any additional functions, just using extra classes with those operators defined.

In general, I find if constexpr a lot easier to deal with than multiple overloads. And even then, since you tagged this c++20, requires is far superior to enable_if.
Okay so let's start with this. If our types are the same, we just call <=>.
template <class T, class U>
constexpr auto cmp(T const& lhs, U const& rhs) -> std::strong_ordering {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, U>) {
        return lhs <=> rhs;
    } else {
        static_assert(std::is_integral_v<T> and std::is_integral_v<U>);
        // ...
    }
}

That already simplifies things a bunch. Now we've already taken care of the string and the easy integer case. Now we just have the hard integer cases. And there we have three cases to deal with: both have the same signed-ness (either both signed or both unsigned), only T is signed, or only U is signed. We can just deal with those one at a time... with more if constexprs:
template <class T, class U>
constexpr auto cmp(T const& lhs, U const& rhs) -> std::strong_ordering {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, U>) {
        return lhs <=> rhs;
    } else {
        static_assert(std::is_integral_v<T> and std::is_integral_v<U>);
        if constexpr (std::is_signed_v<T> == std::is_signed_v<U>) {
           // in this case, the conversions are value-preserving
           return lhs <=> rhs;
        } else if constexpr (std::is_signed_v<T>) {
           return lhs < 0 ? std::strong_ordering::less
                          : static_cast<std::make_unsigned_t<T>>(lhs) <=> rhs;
        } else {
           return rhs < 0 ? std::strong_ordering::greater
                          : lhs <=> static_cast<std::make_unsigned_t<U>>(rhs);

        }
    }
}

The case where both have the same signed-ness is easy, since lhs <=> rhs will do the right thing after any conversions (e.g. if lhs is an int16_t but rhs is an int64_t, then lhs will get converted to int64_t but that is value-preserving).
Now, let's go over the case where just the left-hand side is signed (but the right-hand side is unsigned):
return lhs < 0 ? std::strong_ordering::less
               : static_cast<std::make_unsigned_t<T>>(lhs) <=> rhs;

We have to explicitly check the negative case: if lhs < 0 that means that clearly lhs < rhs (in the mathematical sense), since rhs >= 0 by construction (it's unsigned). Once we handle that case, then we know that lhs >= 0 which means that converting it to its corresponding unsigned type is value-preserving, and then we can fall-back to <=> at this point since now we're doing an unsigned-unsigned comparison.

It's worth pointing out why we have to do it this way, as opposed to the logic in the OP which is picking a type to cast each side to and making a single call to <=> (I simplified the typing a bit but the meaning is the same - copying integers is free so we don't have to worry about some of this):
using Lhs_t  = std::conditional_t<std::is_signed_v<Lhs> == std::is_signed_v<Rhs>,
                                 Lhs,
                                 std::make_signed_t<Lhs>>;
using Rhs_t  = std::conditional_t<std::is_signed_v<Lhs> == std::is_signed_v<Rhs>,
                                 Rhs,
                                 std::make_signed_t<Rhs>>;

return static_cast<Lhs_t>(lhs) <=> static_cast<Rhs_t>(rhs);

So if the signed-ness is the same, we're just doing lhs <=> rhs, which is fine. But now, consider something like cmp(-1, static_cast<uint8_t>(254)). These have different sign, so we're converting each to their corresponding signed value - that's int(-1) for the left-hand side but it's... int8_t(-2) on the right-hand side. So you end up with greater because you're comparing -1 to -2 instead of less because you need to be comparing -1 to 254.
That is, you're producing the wrong answer in a lot of these mixed-sign cases. As you can see here.
The only way to get away with exactly one comparison is to convert both sides to a signed integer that's wide enough to handle the range of both inputs. Which for my example would be int64_t, but might need to be __int128_t if either side is 64-bit. Or you just resort to two comparisons.

this is helpful too. I want to try it out. Thanks.

I knew the error was complaining about wanting a type and I had given it a value, but I was confused how to proceed.
Looking at the cppreference page again, I saw this:

Template parameters
B...    -   every template argument Bi for which Bi::value is instantiated must be usable as a base class and define member value that is convertible to bool

That helped me understand that std::conjunction actually wanted the predicate classes, and not the values of them.
I changed the declarations to:
    template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
    typename std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_integral<Lhs>, std::is_integral<Rhs>>, std::strong_ordering>
    cmp(Lhs const& lhs, Rhs const& rhs)
    {
        ...
    }

    template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
    typename std::enable_if_t<std::negation_v<std::conjunction<std::is_integral<Lhs>, std::is_integral<Rhs>>>,
                              std::strong_ordering>
    cmp(Lhs const& lhs, Rhs const& rhs)
    {
        ...
    }

and it all compiled and all tests passed.
I leave this question in case it helps someone else struggling like I did.

Because I like the generic-ness of std, I follow the same root:
template<typename A, typename B, typename C, std::perdicate<A, B> F>
    requires std::perdicate<F, C, D> 
constexper bool is_succession(A&& a, B&& b, C&& c, F&& f)
{ 
    using std::forward;

    return forward<F>(f)(forward<A>(a), forward<B>(b))
       and forward<F>(f)(forward<B>(b), forward<C>(c)); 
};

generalizing it to any number of operands would need some voodoo. The prototype would involve std::tuple:
template<typename F, typename ...A>
// requires voodoo_perdicate<F, A...> 
constexper bool is_succession(std::tuple<A&&...>&& a, F&& f);

Implementation of the above generic form is not succinct, specially if proper constraints are required.
But for same type of operands, there are the std::is_sorted and std::ranges::is_sorted algorithms.
The only thing left is to wrap std::cmp_less and freinds into closures and make CPO out of them:
constexpr auto int_less =
[](std::integral auto x, std::integral auto y)
constexpr -> bool
{ return std::cmp_less(x, y); };

constexpr auto int_greater = /*similar*/;

/*Define the 6 variation s*/

Now it's easy to call:
static_assert(is_succession(-1l, 2ul, -1u, int_less));
//-1u is the largest 'unsigned' value

